# How to make sed -i work in both Mac and Ubuntu?

Tags: macos, ubuntu, sed

I am working in both Mac and Ubuntu, so I want to make my script work in both Mac and Ubuntu, but `sed -i` works differently in these two system:

In Ubuntu, it should be:

```
sed -i'' 's/Alt/Dog/g' /tmp/example.txt
```

In Mac, it should be:

```
sed -i '' 's/Alt/Dog/g' /tmp/example.txt
```

Answer (score 7):

To make the same `-i` notation work with both GNU `sed` (Ubuntu, Linux) and BSD `sed` (Mac OS X), you must:

1. Always provide a (non-empty) backup suffix.
2. Attach the suffix to the `-i` option.

Thus:

```
sed -i.bak 's/Alt/Dog/g' /tmp/example.txt
```

will work correctly with both variants of `sed`, creating a backup file `/tmp/example.txt.bak` and overwriting the original `/tmp/example.txt` file with the modified output.  (Be wary of files which have multiple links or are symlinks.)

You cannot use a null suffix (no backup) with the same command line.  On GNU, the empty string is attached to the `-i` option (conceptually — as you show in the question); on BSD, the empty string must be a separate argument.  Never the twain shall meet.